Kotlin gradle error while adding kapt and dagger hilt
Hi have a problem in gradle error message:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction`
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details`

It happen when  i add kapt:
projects/modules
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.4.1" apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt) apply false
}

Gradle module app:
    plugins { alias(libs.plugins.android.application) alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) id("com.google.gms.google-services") kotlin("kapt") }
    
    android { namespace = "com.example.chatapp" compileSdk = 34 defaultConfig { applicationId = "com.example.chatapp" minSdk = 26 targetSdk = 34 versionCode = 1 versionName = "1.0"
    
     testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
    
    implementation(libs.dagger.hilt.android)
    implementation(libs.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools)
    kapt(libs.dagger.hilt.compiler)
    implementation(libs.dagger.hilt.compose)
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-database")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage")

}

Full error message:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:130)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:293)

I have tried to change kapt adding other dependencies and removing dagger nothing works

Use ksp instead of kapt and ksp is faster than kapt. And rebuild the project it solve your issue.
App module
ksp(libs.dagger.hilt.compiler)


i was trying to use ksp but had same issue i fix the problem by deleting android studio lady bug and i downloaded koala version.
